# Convert specific char to int

Tags: c#, winapi, encoding

I have a specific character 'š' and I need its representation in wchar_t type, representing a UTF-16 Unicode character so I can give it to Winapi SendMessage function as wParam and WM_CHAR message. The two byte representation of this char is byte[] { 97, 1 }

The int I need is 154. But with following code I always get 353. Any ideas how to get the 154 instead of 353?

```
char ch = 'š';
byte[] charByte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ch); // reults in byte[] { 97, 1 }

int charInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(charCode, 0); // results in 353, but 154 is correct
```

Comment: `(int)'š'` seems to return 353, too. So does `(int)char.ConvertFromUtf32((int)'š')[0]`. Not exactly sure how, why and what you're trying to accomplish. Have you tried just using `353` and seeing what you will get? Might work.

Comment: why should it return 154?

Comment: Using `Encoding` and `BitConverter` also returns 353. Why do you need 154 specifically?

Comment: So the Unicode character at 154 is the Single Character Introducer. Some sites use the `'š'` character as the preview image, but it is a control character, which means by itself it has no visible representation. As such, the only way you could represent it in a `char` literal is with `'\u009a'`. Note that the character at 353 *is* the `'š'` character, so if you type that character into your literal, it is going to give you a value of 353.

Comment: Wrong question with the wrong expectations. You already have the correct UTF-16 encoded code unit representing the code point you are interested in. Using it with `SendMessage` is so very likely the wrong solution to your problem (which I believe to be UI Automation). In that case, do use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). That's what it's for.

Comment: Which `SendMessage` are you calling? It seems like `SendMessageA` but why not `SendMessageW`? After all, UTF-16 is the native Windows (Win32  API, NTFS) character encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you're looking for *Win-1252* (not *Unicode*, but *ANSI* code page) or alike encoding:

```
 byte result = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes('š'.ToString())[0];

 // 154 
 Console.Write(result);
```

Please, notice, that you should decode `string` (`'š'.ToString()`) not `char`.

Answer (score 2):

353 is the correct value for that character in UTF-16. The value of 154 is for one of the Windows ANSI code pages.